# Wondering if there's any way to see form value object in JSP side

Tags: javascript, jsp

**HTML Part**

```html
<form name="loginForm" action="someUrl.do' />" method="POST" onsubmit="return submitForm()">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="organization" placeholder="Organization" maxlength="40">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Id" maxlength="24" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">       
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
function submitForm() {
  return isValid(); // submit the form value when it's valid
}
```

They say, I can check the form element value through `request.getParameter(FORM_ELEMENT_NAME)` in servlet side but what I'd like to know is if there's any way to see the form value in JSP side, for example, inside of the `submitForm` function. Like we can in javascript by `formElement.value`.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,  i have just given as an example (used alert), u can do as per your requirement.

```
<form name="loginForm" action="someUrl.do' method="POST" onsubmit="return submitForm(this)">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="organization" placeholder="Organization" maxlength="40">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Id" maxlength="24" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">       
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

JavaScript method:-

```
function submitForm(form){
    var flds = form.elements;
    for(i=0; i<flds.length;i++){
        fld = flds[i];
        alert(fld); // Field Object 
        alert(fld.value); // value of each field
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jsp file, you can also get the value as following.

```
<%= request.getParamter("form_element_name") %>
```

To get the all values of the form...

```
request.getParameterMap();
```

For example,

```
<%@ page import = "java.util.Map" %>
<%
    Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();
    for(String parameter : parameters.keySet()) {
        String[] values = parameters.get(parameter);
        //your code here
    }
%>
```

Comment: I'd like to see the format of the entire form value like in javascript, not the individual element value. Can I achieve it?

Comment: you can use request.getParameterMap()

Comment: Where should that code be put? I mean, I tried writing your code inside of the `submitForm()` but it gives me a compiler error.

Comment: Sorry I'm totally new in JSP

Comment: @DongBinKim you cannot put `jsp` code inside `javascript` . Also above code will work only when you submit your `<form>` on same page ..